# WP Ecommerce: Display the "Order Notes" in Sales Log

Tags: php, wordpress, function, e-commerce

I have the following function that adds a column in the Sales Log so that I may show the Order Notes. Adding the column is good and showing the id of each item ($item->id) as test is good. Where I am getting stuck is how to display the actual order notes for each item.

Tried numerous things including ($purchlog_notes->notes);

This adds the column (all good)

```
`function addPurchaseLogColumnHead( $columns ){
    $columns['OrderNotes']=__('Order Notes');
        return $columns; 
    }

add_filter( 'manage_dashboard_page_wpsc-purchase-logs_columns', 'addPurchaseLogColumnHead');`
```

This is where I want to show Order Notes content for each sale (issue)

```
`function addPurchaseLogColumnContent( $default, $column_name, $item ) {
    if ($column_name == 'OrderNotes'){
            echo $item->notes;
        }
    }

add_filter( 'wpsc_manage_purchase_logs_custom_column' , 'addPurchaseLogColumnContent', 10, 3);`
```

Appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.